# Shopify SSL not working with CloudFlare?

Tags: ssl, dns, shopify, ipv6, cloudflare

My Shopify store doesn't work with `Full (Strict) SSL` on CloudFlare.

`Full SSL` on CloudFlare is working for my static pages and assets, but customer authentication is all broken.

Comment: Just a general question. Why would you use CloudFlare for a Shopify site anyway?

Comment: @DavidLazar Because of false analytics. My Shopify store just got hit with 4k bots in the past two days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix: Turn "IPv6 Compatibility" OFF

https://api.cloudflare.com/#zone-settings-change-ipv6-setting

After days of back and forth with Shopify experts, they asked me to disable my AAAA record. I only had a single A record in my DNS Zone, so I assumed they were seeing some IPv6 Cloudflare stuff.
Used the API (link above) to curl and change this setting.

```
curl -X PATCH "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/{zoneID}/settings/ipv6" \
-H "X-Auth-Email: user@example.com" \
-H "X-Auth-Key: {APIkey}" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{"value":"off"}'
```

All my SSL issues immediately solved.